# Output array data on drush error when showing stack trace

Tags: 7, drush, debugging

I'm trying to install a module, but its giving me errors during a drush enable. It shows the stack trace log and I can see it has something to do with the flag_lists_type during the install process. I can see there is an array in the output, but how do you print_r() this so I can get more debugging information?

[image]

Comment: a side note. i managed to fix that error in that screenshot. it was to do with a bad schema install for the module flag_lists... it was setting the field as non-null  for a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XDebug PHP extensions with the following suggested settings:

```
xdebug.default_enable = 1           ; bool: The stacktraces will be shown by default on an error event.
xdebug.collect_vars = 1             ; bool: Gather information about which variables are used in a certain scope.
xdebug.show_local_vars=1            ; int: Generate stack dumps in error situations.
xdebug.collect_assignments=1        ; bool: Controls whether Xdebug should add variable assignments to function traces.
xdebug.collect_params=4             ; int1-4: Collect the parameters passed to functions when a function call is recorded.
xdebug.collect_return=1             ; bool: Write the return value of function calls to the trace files.
xdebug.var_display_max_children=256 ; int: Amount of array children and object's properties are shown.
xdebug.var_display_max_data=1024    ; int: Max string length that is shown when variables are displayed.
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=5      ; int: How many nested levels of array/object elements are displayed.
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0             ; int: Show the difference in memory usage between function calls.
xdebug.show_exception_trace=1       ; bool: Show a stack trace whenever an exception is raised.
xdebug.max_nesting_level=256        ; int: Controls the protection mechanism for infinite recursion protection.
```

Since you're experiencing *Exception* type of error, enabling `show_exception_trace` will show a stack trace whenever an Exception or Error is raised (even if this Exception or Error is actually caught, so you can always disable it). Enabling `collect_params`, will display the parameters passed to functions when a function call is recorded (including content of the arrays).

See: [Xdebug documentation page](https://xdebug.org/docs/all).

To verify your XDebug settings from CLI, run:

```
php -i | grep xdebug
```